# Python 3 insert problems

Tags: python-3.x, list, while-loop, insert, try-catch

So I've just started learning python and new to programming in general. Im making a code to answer the Hackerrank learning code "Lists"
([Here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-lists/problem))

I'm having issues using lists and I've made a program to edit a list multiple times but for some reason if I use the .insert() it works with some inputs but not others. I apologize if this is poorly explained.

If I enter "insert 1 55" it inserts 55 to ML[1](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-lists/problem) however if I type "insert 1 48" it adds 1 to ML[1](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-lists/problem) so I'm confused as to why it reacts differently to different value inputs.

Any help will be much appreciated!

---

```
import math

ML=[]

while True:
 try:
  List1=input().split()
  List2=map(int, List1[1:])
  List3=list(set(List2))

  if List1[0]=="insert":
   ML.insert((List3[0]), (List3[1]))
  elif List1[0]=="print":
   print(ML)
  elif List1[0]=="remove":
   ML.remove(List3[0])
  elif List1[0]=="append":
   ML.append(List3[0])
  elif List1[0]=="sort":
   ML.sort()
  elif List1[0]=="pop":
   ML.pop()
  elif List1[0]=="reverse":
   ML.reverse()
  else:
   pass
 except ValueError:
  print("oops")
```

---

Output:

insert 1 55

Print

[55]

Insert 1 44

Print

[55, 44]

Insert 1 48

Print

[55, 44, 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this was a very interesting question, I figured out the issue, it's in this line:

```
List3=list(set(List2))
```

The issue is that set is changing the order of the list:

```
>>> set([1, 48])
{48, 1}
>>> set([1, 50])
{1, 50}
```

So the solution is just remove that `set()` and just do `List3 = list(List2)`. I'm guessing the reason you get a different order is because a set does not track order since it's implemented as a hashtable.

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you again!

Comment: You're too kind :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it seems logical!
There are issues just for 48.
I don't know why till know. You can use this to fix it :

```
List3 = list(List2)
```